# connect expo react native with mysql server on android device

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native, api

I have successful to connect my react native app with MySQL server if I try the code that I implement using laptop web it works well all the data I enter it will store into the database that I have created but when I run on my android device it can't store the data into the database

```
 export default class Scanner extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {userid: ''};
  }
    Register = () => {
    let userid = this.state.userid;
   
    let InsertAPIURL = "https://localhost/api/insert.php";

      let headers = {
        
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS',

        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Api-Key, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
      }
      let Data = {
        userid: userid,
        
      };

      fetch(InsertAPIURL, {
        mode:'no-cors',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(Data)
      })
      try{
        ((response) =>response.json()),
      ((response)=>{
        alert(response[0].Message);
      })
      }
      
      catch{
        ((error) => {
        alert("Error"+error);
      })
    }
}

  
    render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.ViewStyle}>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder={"Member No"}
          placeholderTextColor={"tomato"}
          keyboardType={"numeric"}
          style={styles.txtStyle}
          onChangeText={userid => this.setState({userid})}
        />
        <Button
          title={"Register"}
          onPress={this.Register}
        />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

the problem probably happen on the URL but how should I edit it.

Comment: I have tried using 'http://10.0.2.2/api/insert.php' instead of 'http://localhost/api/insert.php' but it seem like can't solve the issue also